# Should I reuse a model instance in XNA?

Tags: c#, model, xna

In XNA, I instantiate models like:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    this.model = this.Game.Content.Load<Model>("Units/Vehicles/Palladium");

    base.LoadContent();
}
```

I do this in classes like Tank. What I am asking here is that should I instantiate that model instance (load it) for every Tank instance, or should I do it once and assign it to a, say, static property to that Tank class?

I am not sure if tanks instances need all their own instances, but I am also not sure if instantiating new models is pricey or not in terms of performance.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [MSDN for the ContentManager.Load generic method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197848.aspx):

> **Return Value**
>
> The loaded asset. Repeated calls to
>   load the same asset will return the
>   same object instance.

So in essence from your perspective, while the answer is "only load the model once and reuse it across instances", the [ContentManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.contentmanager.aspx) class handles that for you.